# Store subclass does not work in extjs

Tags: extjs6, extjs6-classic, extjs-stores

I have created a class like

```
 Ext.define('abc.StoreService', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
     autoLoad: true,
     autoSync: true,
     proxy: {
         type: 'memory',
         reader: 'json',
         data: [{
             date: "2016-07-15",
             arrival: 'Foo',
             dep: 'abc'
         }]
     },
}

 Ext.define('abc.mystore.Store', {
     extend: 'abc.StoreService',
     alias: 'Abc Store',
    });
```

But if i use in grid like

```
store: 'abc.mystore.Store',
```

or use

```
store: 'Abc Store',
```

it does not load the store data. Is there any thing wrong i am doing?

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning a store id, or registering the store with the StoreManager.

The 'store' parameter in Ext.grid.Panel takes either a store instance (which you could make by doing `Ext.create('abc.mystore.Store')`, or an id of a store registered in the StoreManager.